# Having issue using Arduino IRQ handler in nRF51822

Tags: interrupt, nrf51

Could anyone please help me as I currently using [nRF51822-Arduino](https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF51822-Arduino) library with a nRF51822 chip and I couldn't call the interrupt function, `wakeUp()`.

Currently I connect the external interrupt pin to nRF51822 pin: P0_1 or arduino pin: A0 after pin transform in the nRF51822-Arduino library. Maybe I know what value should I put for the variable `pin` for the function below:

```
attachInterrupt(pin, wakeUp, CHANGE);
```

so that when there is an interrupt change, it will call the `wakeUp()` function?

Comment: Have to managed to get the example, [External_Interrupter.ino](https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF51822-Arduino/blob/S130/arduino-1.6.x/hardware/RBL/RBL_nRF51822/libraries/nRF_Examples/examples/External_Interrupter/External_Interrupter.ino), running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code for the attachInterrupt() shows that you should use the Arduino Pin number:
https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF51822-Arduino/blob/S130/arduino-1.6.x/hardware/RBL/RBL_nRF51822/cores/RBL_nRF51822/wiring_interrupter.cpp#L70

The Arduino Pin number for A0 is 19 according to the pin transformation:
https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF51822-Arduino/blob/S130/arduino-1.6.x/hardware/RBL/RBL_nRF51822/cores/RBL_nRF51822/pin_transform.cpp#L64

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Mikael, what you trying to say is to put value 19 for the pin variable? I have try it but it is not working as well.

Comment: I can setup the interrupt and trigger to check whether any interrupt is coming out from the Adxl345 chip. It change between 1 and 0 but it can't trigger the Interrupt handler.

Comment: As I understand in Arduino, for example Arduino Uno digital pin 2 and 3 is for interrupt and the "pin" variable should put to 0 when using D2 and 1 when using D3.